# How to solve Ubuntu 22.04 startup application preferences issue?

Tags: 22.04, startup-applications

So I have installed Skype and Teams on my laptop. And I have removed them from Startup Application Preferences. But whenever I opened Skype or Teams they are again added to startup. How to fix this issue?

Comment: Disable it in the app settings. Skype has it for sure.

Comment: Alright, thanks, man!

Comment: So does teams! :)